# CSS set height of element to % of automatic height

Tags: html, css, input, height

I am looking for a way in CSS to set the height of a text input to a percent of the normal height it would be given naturally given font-family/font-sizes, if the height was not declared. I am *not* looking for a percent of the height of the container it is in. Like so:
CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
    height: [I want this 150% of the height normally assigned to the element]
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
#results {
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<input type="text">
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: means you want to set height according to container then set height:auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `em`:

```
(...)
height: 1.5em;
(...)
```

#### Edit

Always good to [remember](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#numbers):

4.3.1 Integers and real numbers

> Some value types may have integer values (denoted by ) or
>   real number values (denoted by ). Real numbers and integers
>   are specified in decimal notation only. An  consists of one
>   or more digits "0" to "9". A  can either be an , **or
>   it can be zero or more digits followed by a dot (.)** followed by one or
>   more digits. Both integers and real numbers may be preceded by a "-"
>   or "+" to indicate the sign. -0 is equivalent to 0 and is not a
>   negative number.
>
> Note that many properties that allow an integer or real number as a
>   value actually restrict the value to some range, often to a
>   non-negative value.

So `1,5em` was garbage, sorry!

#### Edit

Your comment about `em` is correct, [see](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units):

> The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size'
>   property of the element on which it is used. The exception is when
>   'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size' property itself, in which
>   case it refers to the font size of the parent element. It may be used
>   for vertical or horizontal measurement. (This unit is also sometimes
>   called the quad-width in typographic texts.)

Comment: Obviously not too sure. `1.5em` was not playing nice with my browser for some reason. However, as I increased it to `3.0em` it was clearly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If you use comma instead of dot, for decimal, is it different ?

Comment: Yes, but not noticeably. I don't know what the difference is. In the jsfiddle that you made, it is noticeably different, but in the browser (FF) practically the same.

Comment: Though, to be honest, 1.5/1,5, though larger, doesn't look exactly like 150% of the original height. Since em is primarily used with typography, I wonder if it is calculating the height based on a 1,5em font size? So, if the original font was 10pt, it is giving it a default height as if it was 15pt font in input.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is in play, you could do something like:

`$('input').css('height',parseFloat($('input').css('height'))*1.5)`

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghxh8/